# Jquery, AJAX and URL changes

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Jquery, AJAX and URL changes...

I have a gallery, and when the image change i would like to change my url to "#image_id=321"
and when i load an url with this appended: "#image_id=321", loads the image with id 321.

is this possible to make without the "#" and using "/photo-id/321"?
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update: Time moves on, while the below was true at the time of writing, we now we have [pushState and friends](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history#Adding_and_modifying_history_entries) as [used by Github](https://github.com/blog/760-the-tree-slider).

---

No. If you change anything more than the fragment identifier, you change the page, and it is no longer Ajax.

As a rule of thumb, if the information is significant enough to bookmark, then Ajax is probably going to cause more harm than good.

Comment: I use like this: '/image_id/33' is the same as 'image_id/12#image_id=33'...

and i really need ajax, because i dont want to make users to lose their time everytmie they want to view a new image.. with ajax is a lot faster..

Comment: I'd say "if the information is significant enough to bookmark, and you must use Ajax, render a fragment identifier, then ensure your code properly handles those identifiers in js to get the user back to where there were."

Comment: may you give me an example, please?

Comment: And example of what? Doing what you are doing already but don't want to?